# Let $\{a_n\}$ be a convergent sequence with $a_n \Rightarrow L$ as $n \Rightarrow \infty$. Prove that $ca_n \Rightarrow cL$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Question: Let $\{a_n\}$ be a convergent sequence with $a_n \Rightarrow L$ as $n \Rightarrow \infty$.

Prove that $ca_n \Rightarrow cL$

WTS:

Let $c \in R$

$\exists L \in R, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N > 0$ such that for all $n \in N$, if $n > N$, then $|a_n - L| < \frac{\epsilon}{|c|}$

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary

Choose N = $(\text{We dont know yet}) > 0$

Suppose $n > N$, then

$$|ca_n - cL| = |c| |a_n - L|$$

$$< |c| \frac{\epsilon}{|c|}$$

$$= \epsilon$$

What do I let N = ?

Comment: You have the right $N$. Choose $N$ such that $|a_n - L| \le \frac{\epsilon}{|c|}$ for all $n \ge N$.

Comment: OH. Thank you. I'm too use to a standard proof were I let N = something. (Do you mean greater than, not greater than equal too btw?)

Comment: Like: Choose N such that for $n > N$ we have $|a_n - L| < \frac{\epsilon}{|c|}$.

Comment: Yes, you can do this because $a_n \to L$ by assumption, so such an $N$ exists for any $\epsilon$ of your choice.

Comment: Another way to say this is "Let $c\in \mathbb R$. Then given $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $N\in \mathbb N$ such that $\forall n >N \in \mathbb N$ we have $|a_n-L| <\frac{\varepsilon}{|c|}$." So....(continue your proof here)

Comment: Adding to what has already been pointed out. On your 2nd line you white the formal definition of $a_n\to L$, which we assert to be true. That lane contains "$\exists N$" which means that, by the assertion there, there must be an $N$ that satisfies the inequality $n>N \implies |a_n-L|<\frac \epsilon{|c|}$. We don't actually care what this $N$ is, so long as we can be sure it exists.

Comment: A more standard notation would be $a_n \to L$.